# Using twitter-bootstrap-rails `nav_bar` helper method in admin namespace not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers, twitter-bootstrap-rails

So, I'm using `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and this gem has a `nav_bar` helper method that is being loaded automatically. But if I want to use this helper method method in a namespaced view I get the error message `undefined method nav_bar`:

```
# views/admin/shared/_menu.html.erb
<%= nav_bar fixed: :top, brand: 'AdminArea', responsive: true do %>
  <%= menu_group do %>
    <%= menu_item 'Articles', admin_articles_url %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So I guess, since the view is being rendered in a namespaced controller the helper method is not being recognized since the helper method is in the "regular" application namespace?
How do I fix this?

Comment: Instead of using helper methods, isn't it easier to just follow the Bootstrap documentation and apply the styles yourself? There is no need for a gem to do this, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem until I used the latest gem directly from git. Put the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

Solves the problem for me.